# using @parameter annotation in testng test case throwing exception

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, jenkins

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters("folderName")
public void setUp(String folderName) {
    createLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),folderName);
    configureDriver();
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    shutDown();
}
```

When I run the above test case using maven

```
 mvn path/to/pom.xml clean -Dtest=HerveLeger test
```

It's giving following exception

```
setUp(com.hb.MFA.HerveLeger)  Time elapsed: 0.359 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'folderName' is required by @Configuration on method setUp_HerveLeger but has not been marked @Optional or defined

at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:155)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:358)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:113)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Here it is my TestNG.xml file

```
<test name="TEST NAME"> 
    <parameter name="folderName" value="TEstName"></parameter> 
    <classes> 
        <class name="com.org.Test" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Please help me any one to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
Parameter 'folderName' is required by @Configuration on method setUp_HerveLeger but has not been marked @Optional or defined
```

It says it right in the exception description. You need to define a parameter in you're TestNG XML file or provide an optional value.

```
@Parameters("folderName")
public void setUp(@Optional("Insert folder name here or leave empty") String folderName) {
```

It is explained clearly in the TestNG Documentation: [TestNG Parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)

Example TestNG.xml

```
<suite name="testSuiteNameHere">
<parameter name="folderName" value="SomeValue"/>
</suite>
```

Comment: Hello @CodeBreaker, I have tried your solution, Now it is not throwing any exception but it always taking the "Insert folder name here or leave empty" value instead of folderName

Comment: @QAMember per TestNG docs "If no parameter is found in your testng.xml file, your test method will receive the default value specified inside the @ Optional annotation." You need to define a folder name parameter in your TestNG Xml file

Comment: Yes I have defined the parameter attribute with its value in TestNG.xml file

Comment: There must be a config error or typo somewhere if it isn't picking it up. Make sure your maven config is registering the xml file or it is being passed correctly via  command line

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mvn path/to/pom.xml clean -Dtest={testname} -DfolderName=HerveLeger test
```

Also you can try, removing @parameters and add simple java call

`System.getProperty("folderName");`

and pass it with

`-DfolderName="HerveLeger"`

thourgh maven goal